# Possessive 's with inanimate nouns (e.g. programming languages)

Tags: articles, possessives, terminology

It has bothered me for a while. I am a software developer and I keep noticing things like

> the features of the **Java 8's** release
>
> during **C++'s** development period
>
> This method is one of the **Java 8's** Stream API's terminal methods.
>
> How the Use of **Scala's** Features Affects Compile Time?

I am totally confused because *all* the examples seem grammatically wrong to me. Even though they originate from well educated and trusted sources, I never thought of describing the possession in that way.  I was taught we never use *'s* to indicate the possession of *an inanimate object* (or any other thing that can't, by nature, *own*/*possess* something).

> Java 8's release
>
> a Java 8's release
>
> the Java 8's release
>
> the Java 8 release *(the one I fully agree with)*
>
> the release of Java 8 *(also looks fine to me)*

Comment: At some point, "correct" English is however people use it.  So, in theory, all of these are legitimate expressions.  I too dislike the possessive, but mostly for reasons of style.   It's certainly OK to use the possessive for inanimate objects, e.g. *"the car's headlights"*

Comment: @Andrew Is it established and correct English to use in a formal setting?

Comment: @Andrew we don't say *"the Andrew's eyes"*, why would we use *"the"* before *"car's headlights"* if *the* car defines its headlights (the headlights of the car)?

Comment: I'd say it's already being used in a "formal" setting, if it appears in articles about Java programming.    As for the definite article, there are many textbooks and websites that explain when you should use the definite article, when the indefinite article, and when no article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were taught that "we never use 's to indicate the possession of an inanimate object", then note that this is a "rule" that is not followed in practice, even in formal English.

The topic has been discussed at length in [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1031/164776) in [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com). As noted [in the accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/100073/164776), the possessive 's appears even in the English translated Bible (King James Version), which is as formal as English it can get.

*That said...*

When you use possessive 's, **you can't add an article to a proper noun**, such as "Java 8". Therefore, the following phrases from your examples are incorrect:

> *a Java 8's release (use instead: Java 8's release)
>
> *the features of the Java 8's release (use instead: the features of the Java 8 release [=the release of Java 8]. Or: the features of Java 8's release).